# How to set CLFAG and LDFLAG for specific package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a specific error that is asking me to do the following:

```
If libaio is already installed (perhaps from source), try setting the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS environment variables to where it can be found.
```

Looking up the locations of these files, it seems they are roughly here:

```
/usr/include/libaio.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so
```

How might I set the flags for this specific package without perhaps overwriting anything else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more context - what are you trying to do, exactly? Those look like standard header and library locations for a *native* C compiler and should not require additional flags to find. Have you installed the Ubuntu `libaio-dev` package?

Comment: Yes I have installed it the results above are via `dpkg-query -L libaio-dev`; I dont have too much to work with other than trying to get the error message to stop complaining :)

Comment: We have even less to work with. What are you trying to build? What command are you running to do so? When you say “roughly here”, what do you mean by “roughly”? Are the files there or not?